# Rails 4 migrations & scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is the following model:

```
class BeautySalonService < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :name, :cost, :beauty_salon_category, presence: true

    belongs_to :beauty_salon_category

    has_many :beauty_salon_employee_services, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :beauty_salon_employees,             through: :beauty_salon_employee_services

    scope :with_employees, select { |bss| bss.beauty_salon_employees.size > 0 }
end
```

When I try to deploy my code to a production server using Capistrano I get the following error:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "beauty_salon_services" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "beauty_salon_services".* FROM "beauty_salon_services...
```

And this error links to 'scope :with_employees' line. If I comment this line my code works good. What's the trouble may be? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really have `beauty_salon_services` table in your db?

Comment: Where have you defined the beauty_salon_services relation?

Comment: Look at model, the whole information in it

Comment: Can you post your schema of your `beauty_salon_services`?

Answer (score 0):

Scopes are for sql constructs - not ruby filtering of a result set. For that you should just write a regular ruby method.

The reason for the error is that when you run the migration that is presumably going to create this table it winds up loading this model.

```
    scope :with_employees, select { |bss| bss.beauty_salon_employees.size > 0 }
```

Ends up having to execute self.select, ie loading all BeautySalonService objects and call Array's `select` method on it